# CDateTimeCtrl editing short year format

Tags: c++, mfc

If the format of the CDateTimeCtrl is set to "dd.MM.yy", the date-control shows correctly at runtime the date in the format "05.05.15"

But if the user places the cursor into the year-section of the control,
the year switches from "15" to "2015"

By leaving the year-section (for example placing the cursor to the day-section) it re-changes from "2015" to "15"

Is there a possibility to suspend this?

The year-section should always stay in 2-digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It's necessary to derive from `CDateTimeCtrl` overriding such kind of behaviour.

To implement the display is quite simple.
I have implemented `CDateTimeCtrl2Digit` in place of the standard component like a sample of what you have to do. The editing is more complex, I did just a very easy one.

```
CDateTimeCtrl2Digit m_DateTime;
m_DateTime.SetFormat( _T("dd.MM.XX"));
```

The format `XX` is managed by the CDateTimeCtrl2Digitas as call back field:

From MSDN:

> Callback fields In addition to the standard Format Strings and body
>   text, you can also define certain parts of the display as Callback
>   fields. These fields can be used to query the user for information. To
>   declare a callback field, include one or more "X" characters (ASCII
>   Code 88) anywhere in the format string. You can create callback fields
>   that have a unique identity by repeating the "X" character. Thus, the
>   format string "XX dddd MMM dd', 'yyy XXX" contains two unique callback
>   fields, "XX" and "XXX". Like other DTP control fields, callback fields
>   are displayed in left-to-right order based on their location in the
>   format string. When the DTP control parses the format string and
>   encounters a callback field, it sends DTN_FORMAT and DTN_FORMATQUERY
>   notification codes. The format string element corresponding to the
>   callback field is included with the notifications to allow the
>   receiving application to determine which callback field is being
>   queried. The owner of the control must respond to these notifications
>   to ensure that the custom information is properly displayed.

So you have to handle this callback field to display the two digit of the year and all the special editing.
Here is a partially working sample: i mean all the editing is missing, here is a very simple one (I don't handle the arrows keys, only numbers).

I'm quite new in posting code in stackoverflow so forgive me if something is 100% working with simply copy&paste what I wrote!!!

But here is what I did:

```
class CDateTimeCtrl2Digit : public CDateTimeCtrl
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CDateTimeCtrl2Digit )
public:
    CDateTimeCtrl2Digit ();
    virtual ~CDateTimeCtrl2Digit ();

protected:
    int nDigit;
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnDtnFormat(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
    afx_msg void OnDtnFormatquery(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
    afx_msg void OnDtnWmkeydown(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
};
```

And the .cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication1.h"
#include "DateTimeCtrl2Digit.h"

#define GetWindowFont(hwnd) FORWARD_WM_GETFONT((hwnd), SNDMSG)
#define FORWARD_WM_GETFONT(hwnd, fn) (HFONT)(UINT_PTR)(fn)((hwnd), WM_GETFONT, 0L, 0L)

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CDateTimeCtrl2Digit , CDateTimeCtrl)

CDateTimeCtrl2Digit ::CDateTimeCtrl2Digit ()
{
    nDigit = 0;
}

CDateTimeCtrl2Digit ::~CDateTimeCtrl2Digit ()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDateTimeCtrl2Digit , CDateTimeCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(DTN_FORMAT, &CDateTimeCtrl2Digit::OnDtnFormat)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(DTN_FORMATQUERY, &CDateTimeCtrl2Digit::OnDtnFormatquery)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(DTN_WMKEYDOWN, &CDateTimeCtrl2Digit::OnDtnWmkeydown)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CDateTimeCtrl2Digit ::OnDtnFormat(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMDATETIMEFORMAT pDTFormat = reinterpret_cast<LPNMDATETIMEFORMAT>(pNMHDR);

    COleDateTime dt;
    CDateTimeCtrl::GetTime(dt);
    CString year = dt.Format(_T("%y"));
    _tcscpy_s( pDTFormat->szDisplay, year);

    *pResult = 0;
}

void CDateTimeCtrl2Digit ::OnDtnFormatquery(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMDATETIMEFORMATQUERY pDTFmtQuery = reinterpret_cast<LPNMDATETIMEFORMATQUERY>(pNMHDR);

    HDC hdc;
    HFONT hFont, hOrigFont;
    hdc = ::GetDC(m_hWnd);
    hFont = FORWARD_WM_GETFONT(m_hWnd, ::SendMessage);
    if(!hFont) hFont = (HFONT)::GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
    hOrigFont = (HFONT)::SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
    ::GetTextExtentPoint32 (hdc, _T("88"), 2, &pDTFmtQuery->szMax);
    ::SelectObject(hdc,hOrigFont);
    ::ReleaseDC(m_hWnd, hdc);

    *pResult = 0;
}

void CMyDateTimeCtrl::OnDtnWmkeydown(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    COleDateTime oCurTime;
    GetTime(oCurTime);
    int century = static_cast<int>( oCurTime.GetYear() / 100 ) * 100;
    int decade = oCurTime.GetYear() - century;
    LPNMDATETIMEWMKEYDOWN pDTKeyDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMDATETIMEWMKEYDOWN>(pNMHDR);
    if( ( pDTKeyDown->nVirtKey >= 48 ) && ( pDTKeyDown->nVirtKey <= 57 ) )
    {
        if( nDigit == 0 )
        {
            nDigit = 1;
            pDTKeyDown->st.wYear = century + pDTKeyDown->nVirtKey - 48;
        }
        else 
        {
            nDigit = 0;
            pDTKeyDown->st.wYear = century + decade * 10 + pDTKeyDown->nVirtKey - 48;
        }
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```